# Why does the piped data between two process seem truncated when too big?

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, subprocess, pipe, ipc

We latelly encountered a problem on our project while trying to make a subprocess pipe a whole base64 encoded picture (around 355K) to it's parent process : but pictures seemed randomly truncated and we still don't get this behaviour nor found a solution.

We found a workaround to transmit these pictures with tempfile based communication, but we still wanna understand the problem about these inter-process communication limitations.

Here is the closest minimum and reproductible example we succeeded to produce that highlights this behaviour, we have a python script that tries to retrieve the data from a node subprocess that generates the data to retrieve.
But the length of data the parent process is able to get seems limited in a nondeterministic way.

This example tests the equality between the requested data length and the actual retrieved length.

- **test.py** :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import base64
import sys
import json
import subprocess

def test(l, executable):
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        executable,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input=json.dumps(l).encode())
    exit_code = process.returncode

    if exit_code != 0:
        raise RuntimeError("fail  : " + str(stderr))

    result = base64.b64decode(stdout.decode("utf-8"))
    assert len(result) == l, f"{len(result)} != {l}"
    print(f"Success: {len(result)} == {l}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = int(sys.argv[1]) if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 355000
    try:
        test(l, ["./test.js"])
    except AssertionError as e:
        print("fail :", e)
```

- **test.js** :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const http = require("http");
const serveHandler = require("serve-handler");
const btoa = require("btoa");

const EXIT_CODE_SUCCESS = 0;
const EXIT_CODE_ERROR = 4;


async function getDataFromStdin() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let receivedData = '';

        process.stdin.on("data", chunk => {
            receivedData += chunk.toString();
        });

        process.stdin.on("end", () => {
            result = resolve(JSON.parse(receivedData)); 
            return result;
        });
    })
}

async function main(){
    const len  = await getDataFromStdin();
    const base64 = btoa("0".repeat(Number(len)));
    process.stdout.write(base64);    
}

let errorCode = EXIT_CODE_SUCCESS;
main()
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        errorCode = EXIT_CODE_ERROR;
    }).finally(() => {
        process.exit(errorCode);
    });
```

- **output** :

```
vagrant@sc-dev-machine:/home/vagrant $ ./test.py 1
Success: 1 == 1
vagrant@sc-dev-machine:/home/vagrant $ ./test.py 1000
Success: 1000 == 1000
vagrant@sc-dev-machine:/home/vagrant $ ./test.py 30000
Success: 30000 == 30000
vagrant@sc-dev-machine:/home/vagrant $ ./test.py 60000
fail : 49152 != 60000
vagrant@sc-dev-machine:/home/vagrant $ ./test.py 60000
Success: 60000 == 60000
vagrant@sc-dev-machine:/home/vagrant $ ./test.py 120000
fail : 49152 != 120000
vagrant@sc-dev-machine:/home/vagrant $ ./test.py 120000
fail : 98304 != 120000
vagrant@sc-dev-machine:/home/vagrant $
```

We also tried with a [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) based solution, without a better result.

What's could the explanation for this be? EOF terminated chunks of data between the processes and through the pipe? Shouldn't buffering (which we suspect to be the cause) be able to transmit the whole data?

Is there a proven approach to transmit data (like files or pictures) through process without length-related limitations?

---

*edit :*
Here are also some informations about the environment :

```
vagrant@sc-dev-machine:/home/vagrant $ uname -a
Linux sc-dev-machine 4.15.0-74-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 08:06:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
vagrant@sc-dev-machine:/home/vagrant $ python3 --version
Python 3.6.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your JavaScript code and you can find the explanation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) :

> Calling `process.exit()` will force the process to exit as quickly as possible even if there are still asynchronous operations pending that have not yet completed fully, including I/O operations to `process.stdout` and `process.stderr`.

and :

> In most situations, it is not actually necessary to call `process.exit()`  explicitly. The Node.js process will exit on its own if there is no additional work pending in the event loop. The `process.exitCode` property can be set to tell the process which exit code to use when the process exits gracefully.

You are calling `process.exit()` before the call to `process.stdout.write()` has completed ([writing to pipes is asynchronous on POSIX](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_a_note_on_process_i_o)). This causes the JS process to exit prematurely, and interrupts the writing before all the data has been written.

If you want to set the error code, you should set `process.exitCode = errorCode` as you do and allow the event loop to end gracefully without calling `process.exit()`.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the answer @vmonteco.